# javascript - type cast of Custom object

Tags: javascript, types, casting

I have 2 custom classes:

//first class

```
var MyPoint = function(x, y, size) {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
};

MyPoint.prototype.paint = function(ctx) {
    //do some drawing in here
}
```

//second class

```
var MyPath = function(a, b, c) {

    this.myPoints = new Array(); //array of the MyPoint objects
    this.size = 0;  //the size of the myPoints array
};

//add function add an object of MyPoint to the myPoints array
MyPath.prototype.add = function(mp) {
   index = 0;
   id (size > 0) {
       index = size -1;
    }
   this.myPoints[index] = mp;
   size++;
}

MyPath.prototype.paint = function(ctx) {

    for(I = 0; I < this.size; I++ {
        this.myPoints[I].paint(ctx);  //this is where my problem is
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is the last line.  When I ran this code, the error was that the paint method was undefined.  When I tried to cast the array element at the ith position to MyPoint using ((MyPoint)this.myPoints[I].paint(ctx),
I got the syntax error.  How do I type cast properly?

Comment: Javascript does not have types or casting.  Your actual problem is that the array is empty.

Comment: @SLaks There are most definitely types and casting in JavaScript. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp

Comment: @Gavin: That is not casting, and those aren't compile-time types the way the question implies.

Comment: @SLaks, sorry I omitted some code..my array is not empty.  I do call the add function to add objects to the array.  See my edited code

Comment: `this.myPoints[index] = mp;` is wrong.since you're using an Array, just push() to it instead of managing indexes. that also means you can use `.length` instead of tracking `size`

Comment: ok, let me try that...thanks

Comment: @dandavis, thank you for your answer.  I changed my code to use push() and that resolved my issue.  Thank you so much